Why does generate_for option not work with aggregate builder
When using an aggregate builder, I notice that the generate_for option on the TargetBuilderConfig in the build.yaml changes behaviour. The builder will only output if the target builder is set to default where as for normal builders setting the generate_for does work as expected.
This is my folder structure
lib
- entity_a.dart
- entity_b.dart
protos

where using the default generate_for of ** seems to work and outputs one proto file with aggregated content in the protos folder. But upon setting the generate_for to lib/**.dart it will stop outputting the proto file. But why?
This is my target build.yaml
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      package_name|builder_name:
        enabled: true
        generate_for:
          - lib/**.dart

Which only works when removing the generate_for. And this is my build.yaml in my generator package.
builders:
  builder_name:
    import: "package:package_name/builders.dart"
    builder_factories: ["build"]
    build_extensions: {'$package$': ['protos/model.proto']}
    build_to: source
    auto_apply: root_package

And this is my builder
import 'package:build/build.dart';
import 'package:glob/glob.dart';

Builder build(BuilderOptions options) => ProtoBuilder();

class ProtoBuilder implements Builder {
  static final _allFilesInLib = Glob('**.dart');

  static AssetId _allDartFiles(BuildStep buildStep) {
    return AssetId(
      buildStep.inputId.package,
      'protos/model.proto',
    );
  }

  @override
  Map<String, List<String>> get buildExtensions {
    return const {
      r'$package$': ['protos/model.proto'],
    };
  }

  @override
  Future<void> build(BuildStep buildStep) async {
    final files = <String>[];
    await for (final input in buildStep.findAssets(_allFilesInLib)) {
      files.add(input.path);
    }
    final output = _allDartFiles(buildStep);
    return buildStep.writeAsString(output, files.join('\n'));
  }
}


I can't answer your question, but I can reproduce this problem and it appears to be related to the use of the synthetic input $package$, see also builders using synthetic input. Maybe file an issue with the maintainers of build?
As a work-around I would suggest setting sources rather than generate_for:
targets:
  $default:
    builders:
      package_name|builder_name:
        enabled: true
        #generate_for:
          #- lib/*.dart
    sources:
      - lib/src/input_folder/**
      - $package$

With the configuration above and e.g. an additional folder lib/src/input_folder containing the files input1.dart and input2.dart the following output is generated and written to protos/model.proto:
lib/src/input_folder/input1.dart
lib/src/input_folder/input2.dart

